# Query optimizer prefers index scan over index seek

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2012

I am using AdventureWorks2012 database.

I created the following index on `Sales.SalesOrderHeader` table

```
create index i1 on 
sales.salesorderheader(purchaseordernumber,salespersonid)
   include(orderdate,shipdate)
   where purchaseordernumber is not null
   and salespersonid is not null
```

When I run the below query:

```
select 
    PurchaseOrderNumber,
    OrderDate,
    ShipDate,
    SalesPErsonId

from sales.salesorderheader
where purchaseordernumber like '%po5%' and salespersonid is not null
```

I expect an Index seek not an index scan, as all of the columns which are part of the query are already part of the index.

I read somewhere that if the query optimizer feels that index scan is cheaper than index seek, then we will index scan.
But, I don't understand why it's happening in this case. We don't have a lookup at all.

Can someone explain me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index works just like a phonebook.  Where would you look for `%po5%` in a phonebook?  You'd have to read the entire phonebook, because you don't know the first character.

That's why SQL Server scans the entire index.  It does not have enough information to seek.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. The moment I remove the first %, then it starts working.